# Safest way to extract all variable refs from xpath expression in java

Tags: java, xpath, saxon, xpath-2.0

I'm using java and saxon processor.

Let say I have some XPath expression with possible variable refs in it. I also have some custom xpath functions which can be nested to arbitrary depth which can have variable refs as parameters. So xpath expression is pretty complex.

I'd like to extract prefix and localname for every variable ref in xpath expression without evaluating it.

I can extract it by setting some custom XPathVariableResolver to my xpath and by evaluating it. But this can make pretty overhead as I only want variable refs to extract, not to call custom functions which can be time consuming.

Is it safe to do it just by some pattern matching with '$' sign?
Probably some API call for this would be great. Or if no API call is available, then which cases I should avoid with '$' sign (probably it can be located as string and I need to avoid taking that one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the s9api XPathCompiler class to compile the expression:

```
XPathCompiler c = new Processor(false).newXPathCompiler();
c.setAllowUndeclaredVariables(true);
XPathExecutable exp = c.compile(xpathExpression);
```

The external variables in the expression are then available by calling:

```
exp.iterateExternalVariables();
```

By the way, it's hit and miss whether Saxon questions get noticed here. If you want to be sure of an answer, use the Saxon forum at http://saxonica.plan.io/

Comment: It seems that we don't have saxonica, only this saxon free open source part. I don't have access to API you written up here? Is there a some other way?

Comment: I expected for xpath.compile() to use xpath resolver and ask me for every particular variable, but that is not the case. :/

Comment: The interface described is available in Saxon-HE 9.4.

Comment: I'm getting this error at first line: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.saxon.Configuration.setProcessor(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
 at net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor.<init>(Processor.java:60)
Can be this coused by some interference with other saxon jar I have in project?

Comment: NoSuchMethodError generally means you've compiled with one version of a JAR file on your classpath and you are executing with a different version of the JAR file.

Comment: Thanks Michael Kay, this will be the way to go. :)

Comment: Just one more question, is it possible to do this in Saxon 9.0 api?

Comment: As mentioned above, it's in Saxon-HE 9.4, and I suspect (without careful checking) that it's not in any earlier release.

Comment: I need it for 9.0 version, I thought 9.4 would do the job, but it seems that we need to use 9.0 saxon-B. Is there a way to do it with some casting to *Impl classes, or with extending some classes and overriding some methods (like IndependentContext or XpathCompiler, or anything)? Any help will be welcome.

Comment: No, I wouldn't have added the feature in 9.4 if there was already a way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

**In case every variable is declared (which must be so in a single stylesheet module, you can simply use this XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
doc(yourUri)//xsl:variable/@name/string()
```

where the namespace prefix `"xsl"` must be registered to the namespace `"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` .

**Or from an XSLT stylesheet**:

```
document(yourUri)//xsl:variable/@name/string()
```

**You probably want also to get all parameter names**:

```
doc(yourUri)//xsl:param/@name/string()
```

**Or, both variable and parameter names**:

```
doc(yourUri)//*[self::xsl:variable or self::xsl:param]/@name/string()
```

**Now, this doesn't get you the set of variables defined within XPath expressions**. To do this you'd need an XPath 2.0 parser (and lexer). In the past I developed such (using the **[FXSL parsing framework](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-lrParse.xsl?revision=1.7&view=markup)**) but haven't published this parser. If you are interested, let me know and I'll send it to you.

**Alternatively**, for a predefined subset of XSLT atribute names you can analyze their values and retrieve a dollar possibly followed by whitespace, then followed by a name. And all this must not be within single or double quotes. Such a regular expression isn't too difficult to write.

**As a last step, you'd have to dedup the so obtained variable references** -- for example using `xsl:for-each-group`

---

**Update**:

**Here is a fragment of the XPath 2.0 grammar I am using**:

```
VariableReference   : '$'     QName

QName         : QNAME2 

                  |  OR
                  |  AND
                  |  EQ
                  |  NE
                  |  LT
                  |  LE
                  |  GT
                  |  GE
                  |  IS
                  |  TO
                  |  DIV
                  |  IDIV
                  |  MOD
                  |  UNION
                  |  INTERSECT
                  |  EXCEPT
                  |  THEN
                  |  ELSE
                  |  IN
                  |  RETURN
                  |  SATISFIES
```

**And the terminal symbol QNAME2  is defined in the lexer in this way**:

```
([\i-[:]][\c-[:]]*:)?[\i-[:]][\c-[:]]*
```

**Of course, even before this one must be sure (recognize) that this is not part of a string literal, which in my lexer I define as**:

```
     ("([^"])*")+
    |
     ('([^'])*')+
```

**Also, you should skip everything that is within comments. I have this Regex for comment start and comment end**:

```
  (\(:)         <!-- Comment start --> 

 |
  (:\))         <!-- Comment end -->
```

Comment: I'm not sure how should I use those xpath expressions to extract variables since I have my xpath expression in String. It is not compiled or anything. I need everything with $ without those variables defined in xpath, as "for $k in ..." this $k should not be collected.

Comment: @Vajda, You probably also don't need `some $x satisfies ...` and `every $x satisfies ...` -- just to name a few. Also, see my update.